# share artifacts between projects on one slave

Tags: testing, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have a master-slave config set up for Jenkins where the master in on a local site, the slaves on AWS. I would like to set up Jenkins such that

- build and
- tests

are separate projects. For this to work, I need to pass the build *artifacts* between the jobs. The artifacts are of the size of several hundred MB. Unfortunately, although all projects are build on the same node, the artifacts are always passed through master, imposing a serious speed penalty.

Is there a way to keep artifacts local to a build slave and pass them between projects there?

Answer (score 1):

On your AWS slave, you can create a shared folder (/jenkins_share).

At the end of your build job, add a post-build step action to copy your artifacts in this folder.

In your tests jobs, add a pre-build step action to get the relevant artifacts from the /jenkins_share folder.

It's not the best solution, but it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Node Stalker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Node+Stalker+Plugin) to share the workspace between two jobs on a build node.

For example, the first job can do the SCM checkout and the build. The second job can run the tests in the same workspace directory without doing another SCM checkout. This also ensures that both jobs are building and testing the same SCM revision, which needs additional setup otherwise.